# how to find column type after decode expression

Tags: sql, oracle

How to show type after decode expression. I,ve following query , and I need know column type of expression decode

**Current Query:**

```
select decode(column1,column2,2,'3') result from tablename
```

Desired Query:

```
 select decode(column1,column2,2,'3') result,calculationoftype.... columntype from tablename
```

Comment: Change `'3'` to `'Z'` and see what happens when `column1` <> `column2`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confused about something.  `decode()` is an expression and it only returns one type.  In your case, that type is `number`.

As the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm) explains:

> Oracle automatically converts the return value to the same datatype as
>   the first result. If the first result has the datatype `CHAR` or if the
>   first result is null, then Oracle converts the return value to the
>   datatype `VARCHAR2`.

In your case the first result is a number, so the return type is a number.

Comment: but query like this works , and it's interesting for me what will be type of result new column

Comment: sorry I understood what you mean

Comment: And how I can see the type of column? is there any function?

Comment: @seyxsultan - you can use [the `dump()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions055.htm) to see the actual data type of a column or expression. The data type codes are also [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF50972). Most of the common ones, anyway.

Comment: @AlexPoole Thank you!